# Pyinstaller executable can't open FortiClient VPN

Tags: python, pyinstaller, forticlient

I have a python program that checks if Forticlient VPN is connected and if it's not, it opens Forticlient.exe and reconnects it. I have created a standalone executable from my program by pyinstaller. I can run the python program from CMD window, but when I try to open stanalone executable I get the error message below. how can I solve this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6EAF.png)

I also got the error below, I noticed that app.asar folder doesn't exist (C:\Program Files\Fortinet\FortiClient\resources\app.asar\assets\js\guimessenger64.node). instead I have app.asar.unpacked (C:\Program Files\Fortinet\FortiClient\resources\app.asar.unpacked\assets\js\guimessenger64.node)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAsbp.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.